# Solve this question according to quantum mechanics for a free particle ($V=0$)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy

[image: quantum mechanics mcq solve this problem with explanation]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bogqi.jpg)

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer  should be b.)

For the case $V=0,$ the stationary schroedinger equation reduces to

$$E \psi = \frac{-\Delta}{2 m} \psi.$$

The solutions are linear combinations of

$$\psi(x)= a_1 exp(-ikx+\phi_1)+a_2 exp(ikx+\phi_2).$$

Therefore the possible energies are given by

$$E=\frac{k^2}{2m},$$

for any $k$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}.$

It should therefore be continuous.